# How read a csv with quotes using sparkcontext

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, spark-graphx

I've started recently to use scala spark, in particular I'm trying to use GraphX in order to make a graph from a csv. To read a csv file with spark context I always do this:

```
val rdd = sc.textFile("file/path")
   .map(line => line.split(","))
```

In this way I obtain an RDD of objects Array[String].
My problem is that the csv file contains strings delimited by quotes ("") and number without quotes, an example of some lines inside the file is the following:

```
"Luke",32,"Rome"
"Mary",43,"London"
"Mario",33,"Berlin"
```

If I use the method split(",") I obtain String objects that inside contain quotes, for instance the string Luke is saved as "Luke" and not as Luke. 
How can I do to not consider quotes and make the correct string objects?
I hope I was clear to explain my problem

Comment: You can also use the scala string replaceAll function to replace leading/trailing quote after you split in the map function

Answer (score 0):

you can let the Spark DataFrame level CSV parser resolve that for you

```
val rdd=spark.read.csv("file/path").rdd.map(_.mkString(",")).map(_.split(","))
```

by the way, you can transform the Row directly to VertexId, (String,String) in the first map based on the Row fields

Answer (score 0):

Try with below example.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
object DataFrameFromCSVFile {

  def main(args:Array[String]):Unit= {

    val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
      .master("local[1]")
      .appName("SparkByExample")
      .getOrCreate()

    val filePath="C://zipcodes.csv"

    //Chaining multiple options
    val df2 = spark.read.options(Map("inferSchema"->"true","sep"->",","header"->"true")).csv(filePath)
    df2.show(false)
    df2.printSchema()

  }
}
```